# Offset issues images when inside group (scaleToWidth)

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm experiencing an issue when scaling an image inside a group the offset of the image changes. The group consists of a background (Rect) and an image. When scaling the group the offset if the image becomes different. Expected is that the offset remains the same as the background.

I'm using Fabric 4.0.0-beta.6

[image]

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(document.body.clientWidth);
canvas.setHeight(document.body.clientHeight);

const bg = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red',
});

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff", function(img) {

  img.scaleToWidth(bg.width)
  const post = new fabric.Group([bg, img], {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
  });

  post.scaleToWidth(400);
  canvas.add(post);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

https://jsbin.com/migogekoxu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `strokeWidth` property of the background element to `0` fixed the offset for me.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(document.body.clientWidth);
canvas.setHeight(document.body.clientHeight);

const bg = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 0, //<---
});

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff", function(img) {

  img.scaleToWidth(bg.width)
  const post = new fabric.Group([bg, img], {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
  });

  post.scaleToWidth(400);
  canvas.add(post);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric@4.0.0-beta.6-browser/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously that's a bug with fabricJS. If you don't want to fix it on your own in it's source code you can workaround it however.

You can manually correct the position by adding an offset of 0.5 to the image's `top` and `left` properties.

For example:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

const bg = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red'
});

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff", function(img) {
  img.scaleToWidth(bg.width);
  img.left += 0.5;
  img.top += 0.5;
  const post = new fabric.Group([bg, img], {
    left: 100,
    top: 100
  });

  post.scaleToWidth(400);
  canvas.add(post);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric@4.0.0-beta.6-browser/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```